# JAVA: Me need sort a series in an array in descending order

Tags: java, arrays

All can not solve one problem. I could do a sizing of the last row in order of growth. But I can’t understand how to do the opposite. I need the last row of the array to sort in descending order (from largest to smallest)

```
package com.test.array;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class first{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] twoDimArray = {
                {3, 5, 9},
                {0, 7, 1},
                {8, 9, 2},
                {1, 4, -8},
                {3, -6, 7},
        };
        printArray(twoDimArray);
        System.out.println("******************");
        System.out.println("Averege first row: " + Arrays.stream(twoDimArray[0]).average());
        Arrays.sort(twoDimArray[twoDimArray.length - 1]);
        printArray(twoDimArray);
        System.out.println("******************");
    }
    private static void printArray(int [][] arr) {
        for (int [] row : arr)
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.sort(twoDimArray[twoDimArray.length - 1], Collections.reverseOrder());` ?

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to give the sample output as well as other things you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the array as you already do, and then iterate the array and swap first with last, second with last-1, etc. Like in the following code snap:

```
 Arrays.sort(twoDimArray[twoDimArray.length - 1]);
 //Swap 
 for (int i = 0, j = twoDimArray[twoDimArray.length - 1].length - 1, tmp; i < j; i++, j--) {
     tmp = twoDimArray[twoDimArray.length - 1][i];
     twoDimArray[twoDimArray.length - 1][i] = twoDimArray[twoDimArray.length - 1][j];
     twoDimArray[twoDimArray.length - 1][j] = tmp;
  }
```

Result of the last row of your 2D array is:

```
[7, 3, -6]
```

You can store the reference of the `twoDimArray[twoDimArray.length-1]` into an array so the code becomes more clear:

```
 int [] a = twoDimArray[twoDimArray.length - 1];
 Arrays.sort(a);
 //Swap
 for (int i = 0, j = a.length - 1, tmp; i < j; i++, j--) {
    tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = tmp;
  }
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(twoDimArray[twoDimArray.length - 1]));
```

As you see the result does not change, as a[] holds a reference of the array `twoDimArray[twoDimArray.length - 1]`

Comment: Thank you. You very helped me)

Answer (score 0):

Write a method to reverse sort an array of `int` primitives.

In this case, because the array is of `int` (primitive) instead of `Integer` object, I think the simplest/best thing to do is to just write a method to sort and reverse the array.  If it was an array of some `Object`, then you should use a `Comparator`.

```
private static void reverseSort(int[] values) {
    Arrays.sort(values);
    reverse(values);
}

private static void reverse(int[] values) {
    final int halfLength = values.length / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < halfLength; i++) {
        swap(values, i, values.length - 1 - i);
    }
}

private static void swap(int[] values, int i, int j) {
    int tmp = values[i];
    values[i] = values[j];
    values[j] = tmp;
}
```